# Share specific directory which is not at the root of the file system using NFS

Tags: nfs, gentoo

I'm exporting the directory: /a/b/c/
Now, when i mount this share from the client, at /mnt/c, in order to access /a/b/c/ on the server i need to access /mnt/c/a/b/c
Is there a way to make /mnt/c show the content of /a/b/c on the server without traversing the entire path?
(I'm using NFS4 on Gentoo)

The exports file on the server contains:

```
/a/b/c/ 10.0.0.100(ro,subtree_check)
```

The client mounts using:

```
mount -t nfs4 10.0.0.99:/ /mnt/c/
```

Comment: Afaik it is not possible without having another export entry but i might be wrong.

Comment: Could you please post the files /etc/exports (you have on the NFS server) and /etc/fstab, or /etc/auto.* (you have on the NFS clients)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,
Instead of mount at the root, i have to mount at the specific directory like so:

```
mount -t nfs4 10.0.0.99:/a/b/c /mnt/c/
```